# TD cell with css decimal percent height gets incorrect actual height in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-tables

As I am trying to create a grid of TD in a table, and that the total height of the TD cells make up 100% of the height of the table, I found that when I set the css height of the TD to a decimal point, the calculated height is larger than expected in Chrome 28 (and that the last few rows becomes squashed). But when I change the css height to a whole number the calculated height becomes correct.

Take a look at the replication of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/RUwLH/3/

In the example, there are 33 rows in each table.

Note that the td cells of each table have different css:

```
.main td {
    width:50%;
    height: 3.03%;    
}

.main2 td{
       width:50%;
    height: 3.00%;    
}
```

The funny thing is that in IE10, the cells seems to show up correctly, but the 2 sets of tables becomes overlapped

In FF16 this works fine.

Anyone know any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug in Webkit based Browsers. But you unnecessarily confuse the table algorithm ...! Why would or should you set the height of each TD explicitly when the table algorithm will do it by itself? So the easiest way to avoid the problem is to simply set no height for the TDs.

See the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RUwLH/4/

```
...
```

From a semantically point of view your code is highly questionable, and giving each of the elements the same class is also very inefficient CSS (hope you just did it for the Fiddle).

After all these years tables are still a "special problem" ...! So only use them for tabular data and nothing else!

HTML and CSS provide a lot of other possibilities which are even more semantically!

Comment: It was some other problem that forced me to perform something like this, the problem shown is exhibited with all the details striped. But you are correct, simple leaving out the percentage will solve the problem.